# Discord.py Advanced Banning

Tags: json, discord, discord.py

So i've asked this question before, but I have changed it up a little bit, but is till won't work. I have been trying and trying but it still won't work. Pretty much, admins can choose a "moderation log" channel. Were it will act like a text channel version of an audit log. This is my current code.

```
    
def get_modlogs(client, message):
    with open('modlogs.json', 'r') as f:
        modlog = json.load(f)
    return modlog[str(message.guild.id)]

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    with open("modlogs.json","r") as f:
        modlog = json.load(f)

        
    if ctx.guild.id in modlog:
        moderation_log_channel = client.get_channel(get_modlogs)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"<:banHammer:768062652563587072> You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} ", color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
        try:
            await member.send(embed=embed)
            await member.ban(reason=f"{reason}---Action done by {ctx.message.author.name}.",delete_message_days = 0)
            embed.add_field(name="Member Banned:", value=f"<@{member.id}>({member.id})", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="By Staff Member:", value=f"<@{ctx.message.author.id}>({ctx.message.author.id})", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            await ctx.send("Member's DM's are closed. They were still banned but they weren't dmed about it.")
            await member.ban(reason=f"{reason}---Action done by {ctx.message.author.name}.",delete_message_days = 0)
            embed.add_field(name="Member Banned:", value=f"<@{member.id}>({member.id})", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="By Staff Member:", value=f"<@{ctx.message.author.id}>({ctx.message.author.id})", inline=False)
            try:
                await moderation_log_channel.send(embed=embed)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            except:
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            
    if not ctx.guild.id in modlog:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"<:banHammer:768062652563587072> You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name} ", color=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
        embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
        try:
            await member.send(embed=embed)
            await member.ban(reason=f"{reason}---Action done by {ctx.message.author.name}.",delete_message_days = 0)
            embed.add_field(name="Member Banned:", value=f"<@{member.id}>({member.id})", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="By Staff Member:", value=f"<@{ctx.message.author.id}>({ctx.message.author.id})", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            await ctx.send("Member's DM's are closed. They were still banned but they weren't dmed about it.")
            await member.ban(reason=f"{reason}---Action done by {ctx.message.author.name}.",delete_message_days = 0)
            embed.add_field(name="Member Banned:", value=f"<@{member.id}>({member.id})", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="By Staff Member:", value=f"<@{ctx.message.author.id}>({ctx.message.author.id})", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It bans perfectly fine, i'm just trying to get it to send the message to the moderation log channel. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the bot able to see the mod channel & does it have permissions to send messages in there? Also, are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes it can see the mod channel, and it has perms too. I'm not getting any errors when doing the command, it just doesn't work.